# What is the difference / relationship between GitHub Projects and Milestones?

Tags: github, project

The recent update to GitHub added something called ***Projects*** into the GitHub workflow, and because I don't have any particular experience with *project tracking tools* such as Jira or Trello *(hey, at least I noticed the similarity)*, could anyone, please, **elaborate on the (key) differences** between GitHub's ***Milestones*** and the new ***Projects***?

If I understand correctly, ***Milestones*** are a way of organizing issues into smaller "sub-projects" - smaller than the whole "project" (which, in my world view, is represented by ***the repository***). When all issues are done/closed, the milestone can be regarded as *complete*.

The newly introduced ***Projects*** are also, as I see it, a way of organizing issues into *smaller-than-the-repository* "sub-projects" (albeit called *Projects*). I understand the workflow is supposed to be slightly different and more fine-grained than with "mere" ***Milestones***.

So, are *Projects* something that supplements *Milestones* (or rather *Milestones* supplement *Projects* now?) or should I rather view *Projects* as a ***replacement*** of *Milestones*?

Where exactly do the ***Projects*** actually fall into the `repository[-milestone]-issue` hierarchy?

Sadly, GitHub's blog entry about the introduction of the ***Projects*** doesn't mention any relationship (https://github.com/blog/2256-a-whole-new-github-universe-announcing-new-tools-forums-and-features).

*I somehow feel there is one, but I can't put a finger on it.*

Comment: Since the help center clearly says: _"[...] if your question generally covers [...] software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"_, I don't see any reason for that.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

I'm wondering the exact same thing. Here is what I came up with.

First, let's review the main similarities and differences:

- An issue can belong to multiple Projects, but only one Milestone.
- <del>Projects are never *complete*. There is no progress bar, or deadline.</del> Projects <del>have no progress bar or deadline</del> (they do now, though it is hidden inside the project's menu as a "Track project progress" checkmark, and there's no percentage calculation of progress), but can now be closed (as pointed out by @Sheen)
- Milestones on the other hand have all that, but lack any form of organization. An issue is either in a milestone, or isn't. (They can be ordered as pointed out by @Nick McCurdy)
- <del>Issues can be filtered by Milestone, but not by Project.</del> As pointed out by @cmonkey, issues can now be filtered by Project as well as Milestone.
- Projects can contain *Notes* (which can be converted as issues) so it doesn't pollute the issue tracker with vague ideas
- A Project can span over multiple Milestones, and a Milestone can contains parts of different Projects.
- An Organization can have Projects as well. These projects can include tickets from any repository in the organization, which makes it quite useful.

So the way I see it, is that **Projects** are a completely separate way to visualize and organize your work on an higher level (think "project management", multiple teams, multiple repository, etc.), while **Milestones** are a way to organize your deadlines and releases on a more basic level (think "release management", "versions", etc.). With this in mind, it makes sense that an issue only belongs to one Milestone (it's only released or pushed to production once) but can be part of different Projects.

I'm sure they are other ways to look at it though, and I'm interested to hear other opinions.

### Edit December 2017

Some time ago, after working with Milestones and Projects for over a year, I realized there is another important aspect I had completely overlooked.

- **Milestones** is a tool for **Scrum** methodology. Milestones are good for timeboxed iterations and working in sprints with batches of issues.
- **Projects** is a tool for **Kanban** methodology. Projects are good for continuous delivery and steady flow of work.

Comment: Thanks for the summary, I've been wondering this myself. Think I'm going to stay clear of the whole Projects thing as it's not very applicable for my... projects. Github Projects seems (to me) to be "upside down" because I usually have several repositories to 1 project, not the other way around.

Comment: @KEK, in GitHub Enterprise, I use an organisation with an eponymous repository which has no code, but is used to keep all the projects and their issues centralized. The Pull Requests against the repositories that hold code have a brief reference to the central repository's issue.

Comment: My feeling is that milestones are mostly for the following weeks/months where all the issues are more or less known, and projects are for months up to a year, where not all issues are yet known. A tigher integration between the two reducing the overlap might actually be worthwhile.

Comment: Projects now have progress bars if using column automation presets.

Comment: This is fantastic. However, it's still unclear to me if one should use Milestones and Projects together or should use only one of the two. What do you think?

Answer (score 64):

My opinion:

- A **Project** is about a **process** and the **people**.
- A **Milestone** is about a **product**.

A Project is best for getting insight into a **process** used by the **people** in the group. A better name for it would be "workflow" or "process". There's more overhead involved in creating a new project vs. creating a new Milestone. So you really only want to create a new Project when there's a new **process** in your team: Lanes must be chosen, configured, and ordered. They can also be very different in each Project. I think back to the original use of Kanban by Toyota: managing the people and their workload.

> A Project answers the question, "What are we working on at the moment?"

Two great Project examples: software development and blogging. The configurations for each would support the different groups' people processes; how they work together and sign off on things.

*Milestones, in contrast, all work the same.* They're an ordered list of tasks which must all be closed for the work product to be considered complete. Optionally, a due date can be set, which just provides reminders, but does not change the Milestone functioning.

> A milestone answers the question, "What is remaining to finish this product?"

Answer (score 24):

**Milestones** are kind of labels that mark and group tickets that are expected to be delivered at some point in time. The `Milestones` page which you can access from `Issues` page makes it clear - you can see the percentage of tickets completed for a particular milestone and the due date. You can also sort milestones by due date and prioritise tickets within a particular milestone.

The stress here is on delivery dates and tracking progress.

**Projects** on the other hand are implemented in GitHub as [Kanban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_%28development%29) boards with some bells and whistles. You can specify a number of columns (<s>and *swimlanes*</s> - as @Doug said below *swimlanes* are not supported yet) to create simple workflows. You can then add tickets from one or many repositories, prioritise them, and then progress them from one column to another as they are being worked on. You could, for example, have 'Backlog', 'In Progress', 'Under Review', 'In Testing', and 'Done' columns and move tickets from left to right, or from right to left if, say, a defective ticket gets bounced from 'In Testing' back to 'Backlog'.

The stress here is on organising and managing the work.

Then how you organise and partition that work is up to you. You could create a project per milestone or have several milestones in a single project, or split milestones into shorter [sprints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprint_%28software_development%29). You could also have several projects covering different aspects of working on the product, for example, one for developers and one for testers.

Comment: swimlanes are not columns in Kanban.  They are rows.  Github does not currently support swimlanes as a first class feature.

Comment: So, to put it another way, the concept of Projects is exactly the same as the concept of Jira which also has workflows and columns.

Answer (score 19):

One nice thing about projects is that they're more free-form than milestones. You can just chuck notes in them and link to issues, and organise them however it suits you. They're great for jotting down ideas, making roadmaps, and listing resources and dependencies. In the past I've used issues and the wiki for the same things, but I found both to be too formal and transactional (i.e. higher overhead).

Comment: +1 I'll add that, in my mind, milestones reflect commitments the organization has made in the project's life-cycle, whereas the project board may include half-baked ideas that team members aren't ready to fully buy into yet.

Answer (score 17):

On GitHub:

- The **Project** is a process that has beginning but no ending.
- The **Milestone** is a process that emphasizes the end time.

So it is correct to use milestones to split the project into many stage with end times.

I use it like this:

- **Organization Project** is used to organize the process that about multiple repositories.
- **Repository Project** is used to organize the iterative process of long-term branches, such as develop branch, custom branch.
- **Milestone** is a iteration stage.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Projects and Milestones should now be viewed a little differently since the release of the new Projects functionality, which includes Iterations.

All three should be viewed as something that can be completed (see PMI on the definition of Project).  For scrum, I use Projects for systems, Milestones for major releases, and Iterations for sprints.